# How to use thread for never returned function in C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, opengl, tao-framework

I am new in C# and I want to use thread because in the following code I want to call `Glut.glutMainLoop();` function in for loop but this function never return and it stopped. I think I can use thread.But I dont know how can I do that. Or is there any other solution? Any help would be much appreciated.

```
 static void Main()
            {

               int i;
                 ...
                 ...
                 ...

                  for (i=0 ; i<=10 ; i++) {


                  Glut.glutMainLoop();

               }

          }
```

Comment: how are you handling it now? what do you want to if it is never returned, timeout?

Comment: @ImranRizvi   Glut.glutMainLoop() updates the console. If it is not called again it cannot update.

Comment: glutMainLoop is not meant to be called in a loop. It implements your main loop (that `for` of your code) already for you. Register the proper callbacks with GLUT and don't bother with it. If you really need your own event loop handling use a different framework (GLFW for example).

Answer (score 1):

Having looked at the documentation for [`glutMainLoop`](https://www.opengl.org/documentation/specs/glut/spec3/node14.html), it seems this method initiates Glut's message pump. And that's why it will never return.

It seems to me that you shouldn't be using threads. Once you initiate Glut, it will take over the application and take care of the application's life-cycle for you.

All your logic should go into the callbacks that Glut will call. See:

> It will call as necessary any callbacks that have been registered.